# Webform calculate time difference from 2 timepicker fields place in 3rd field

Tags: javascript, timepicker

I have a webform where the user picks a time in field 1 (start time) and then selects the time in the 2nd field (end time).  The 3rd field is total time and the user currently manually calculates the time and enters it in this field.  Is it possible to have a time calculator (javascript) that will give the result of start and end time difference and enter it into the total time field?  Also I am using a timepicker for the start and end time
thanks

Comment: What is the format of your time string?

Answer (score 0):

The old school way is it to get the times from each timepicker and change those into milliseconds. Then calculate the difference and change it back to your time format. In plain Javascript the Date object is your friend.

PS: As far as I can remember it exists a plugin for JQuery for time calculating. This is properbly more comfortable to use for you.